# Inconsistency from Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently writing a PHP application.

I noticed something strange when it wasn't returning the persons birthday.

To cut a long story short, when i manually query the graph api, it gives me the full result set (birthday, email etc. included). However, when I run it in my app, it comes back as if i've not sent the access token.

When I manually visit the address it produces:

```
{
   "id": "507665705",
   "name": "Ally Dewar",
   "first_name": "Ally",
   "last_name": "Dewar",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/alastair.dewar",
   "username": "alastair.dewar",
   "birthday": "06/22/1990",
   "location": {
      "id": "113744028635772",
      "name": "Greenock"
   },
   "gender": "male",
   "email": "alastair\u0040alastairdewar.co.uk",
   "timezone": 1,
   "locale": "en_GB",
   "verified": true,
   "updated_time": "2012-03-11T15:56:19+0000"
}
```

However, when my application makes the same request (exact same URL), it comes back with

```
{"id":"507665705","name":"Ally Dewar","first_name":"Ally","last_name":"Dewar","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/alastair.dewar","username":"alastair.dewar","gender":"male","email":"alastair\u0040alastairdewar.co.uk","locale":"en_GB"}
```

My instinct says it could be a setting within the facebook app, as it wasn't a problem beforehand.

EDIT: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412680422092698?browse=search_4f854dc037a2a5d12811839

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: you need the credentials by facebook (scope parameter), maybe thats it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you ask for all the permissions that you need and also remove the app and start again. Make sure you ddon't cache any of the responses as well.

How do you query the API? Graph Explorer or just manually open the link (graph.facebook.com/USER_ID) and pass the auth token generated by the app? Testing with the Graph Explorer won't help you with your problem as permissions etc are different.

As mentioned by Nobita, code helps. This is as much as I can advise considering the amount of data you're giving us.